# How to Run a IPhone, IPad App still in development to a device remotely, I'm NY client in Chicago?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I live in New York, my client lives and works in Chicago, I'm developing IOS Apps to run on iphone and ipad for his company, and so far, I've been sending him screenshots of what the App looks like.

I do feel the need of finding a way to make it run on his iphone and ipad in order to allow him to have a look and feel of the solution and browsing it. Today I can just run on my own devices which are connected to my mac and installed when I compile from XCode...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send him [Ad Hoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html) builds, but I really recommend using [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com).

Comment: interesting, I'm checking this out

Comment: followed this question for the same reason, TestFlight is very easy to use, +1 for the recommendation

Answer (score 1):

You will create adhoc builds and send it to them. You will need to get the UDID of their devices and do a special build for it. You can look at the apple documentation in the provisioning portal on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother having UDIDs or building for each device (as is the case for Ad-Hoc builds), checkout [enterprise distribution](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). I've done it and is REALLY comfortable. I would also recommend checking out [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) before this, though.